# Java Line2D linesIntersect broken

Tags: java, math, geometry, line

These two lines are effectively points, but when I run the lineIntersects method I get "true" as a return value, does anyone know what is going on or is this a bug? Here is the [documentation link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Line2D.html#intersectsLine(java.awt.geom.Line2D)) and here is the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/awt/geom/Line2D.java#Line2D.intersectsLine%28java.awt.geom.Line2D%29), neither warn about special cases when this might fail.

```
import java.awt.geom.*;
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    //                              x1,  y1,  x2,  y2
    Line2D l1 = new Line2D.Double( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 );
    Line2D l2 = new Line2D.Double( 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0 );

    System.out.println(l1.intersectsLine(l2)); // true

  }
}
```

FYI i'm running java version "1.8.0_74"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Oracle Java test uses cross products](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/64b0c953635d/src/share/classes/java/awt/geom/Line2D.java#l608) to determine whether each segment's endpoints straddle the infinite line that the other segment is embedded in.  If that's true, then the lines are said to intersect.

The problem is that the cross products degenerate to zero for coincident endpoints, and the "straddling" tests all return true in the case where the points being tested touch the line, which is when the cross product is zero.

Therefore, two points provided as input will always return true.

The geometric interpretation is that a "line" defined by two coincident points is *always* straddled by any other pair of points. So two zero-length lines have endpoints that straddle each other.

This may not be intuitive, but it's consistent. Lots of geometric algorithms do quirky things around degeneracies. If you don't like this behavior, wrap the function and return what you need.

Comment: Moreover, Java's Line2D class accepts "line segments" which by definition is formed using two distinct points. Although, I still think java did a sloppy job allowing this edge case to get through.

Comment: @will.fiset Really all they did wrong was fail to document undefined behavior for degenerate segments. Exact floating point comparisons are just about useless, and doing any kind of epsilon-based calculation is both fairly expensive and unlikely to help most users.